# PHP CSRF Form token + validation advice

Tags: php, forms, csrf

I've got a submission form, with 9 fields, 6 of which require validation, including a upload field with file size and file type validation.

Generating a random token, to prevent CSRF is working, but what is the correct way to validate when using a token?

If I do the validation within the same file, the token is regenerated with the validation reload. (can this be prevented? I've tried `isset()` but still regenerates.) However using the same file prevents the users Name and Email from being stored in a session.

Is it best to do the validation within a separate file, which then redirects back to the form with basic variables in the URL for each error, i.e. `http://www.example.com/form?n=1`

Using a separate file would also mean storing the form data within session, so the form can be repopulated if errors exist on the redirect.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: I found [this article by Chris](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries) very good in explaining what CSRF is and how to protect yourself against it.

Comment: Thanks for that, he has covered it slightly better than in the book.

Comment: Those articles might help you: > [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)
> [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: `md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));` shouldn't be trusted for security contexts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31683058/4357238

Answer (score 1):

From experience, [CodeIgntier](http://codeigniter.com/) does great CSRF [implementation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html), among other security mesures. I would suggest that you go over their code to gain a good understanding of the whole process. Also see [this](http://blog.builtbyprime.com/security/csrf-protection-in-code-igniter-using-form-tokens).