# Secure way to stop users from forging forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, antiforgerytoken

How can I prevent users from forging forms on the PHP or jquery side, I am using Jquery's ajax functionality to submit the forms, and this means that tech-wise people can change some variables such as the value of something (that shouldn't be changed / is a user id or something like that) through the use of firebug or web inspector and likewise.

So how can I prevent users from changing these variables or making sure they are unchangeable through a secure and good way?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, its kind of scary that you think this might be possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly add CSRF token using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287903/how-to-properly-add-csrf-token-using-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others have already stated, you **can't** prevent the user from tampering.

You are receiving data from me, and I can send you anything I want, I can even do an HTTP request by hand, without even using a browser, and you can't do anything about it.

If you don't want a user to be able to alter an information, don't provide it to him.

You can store it in PHP's session, which is stored server side (do not use cookies, they too are sent to the user) or save it in a database, both of them are not accessible to the end user.

If you still want to pass the data to the user, compute some sort of hash (a *secure* hash, using a *secure* hashing algorithm and a *secure* [message digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) as Gumbo [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532356/secure-way-to-stop-users-from-forging-forms#comments-8532507), this rules out algorithms like CRC32 or MD5 and MACs like your name or birthday) of the data and store it server side, then when the user submits back the data, check if the hashes match.

But do know that this solution is not 100% secure. Hashing functions have collisions, and bad implementation exists.

I would recommend to stick to the golden rule: if it's not there, it cant break / be tampered / be stolen / etc.

Comment: Use a proven [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent users from doing so.

Comment: Why? If the variables come from the server they can be bound to a token. If the client submits the form the values don't match the tokens someone forged the request.

Comment: it is not possible to prevent the user from changing page data using javascript or a debugging tool, the server session seems to be the only way to make form submission somewhat reliable, but that is a server-side approach

Comment: Since the OP asked for either PHP (server) or JQuery side.. that would be possible.

Comment: taken this into account the session variables will provide the most reliable feature here

Answer (score 2):

Store these variables in a Session.

Answer (score 2):

You can never trust the client. Validate the form on the server to ensure the data is sane. This means checking that a given user ID has permissions to post their form, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with... you can't. You never trust the user's data; client side verification is always *only* the first line of defense.

Comment: Client-side verification is better to omit when possible

Comment: @Shvelo Why should it be omitted?

Comment: Some article says that.
Not all the machines are fast and powerful,
you can check lengths and stuff, but regex matching is expensive

Comment: No way! Client side validation prevents costly server requests just to have the server tell the user to change their entries.

Comment: I didn't say **not** to use it, I said not to **trust** it. Big difference.