# How do I send an email to the user on submit of php form

Tags: php, html, forms

How do I send an email to the user with the data they submitted in the form that includes a little message using there name and thanking them on submit of php form.

Here is my current php code. It currently just shows them a message that says there name and that the message has been sent and then sends me an email to my email address.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $to = "benlevygraphics@gmail.com";
        $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "Ben, you have been contacted...";
        $body = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\nWebsite: " . $_POST['web'] . "\nMessage: " . $_POST['message'];

        if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){

        echo("<p class=contactformsent>".$_POST['name'].", your message has been sent!</p>");

        }
        else{
           echo("<p class=contactformnotsent>".$_POST['name'].", Message delivery failed...</p>");
        }
   }
?>
```

I am new to php and I have read stuff online and I still don't understand so if you could be clear in your examples or help I would greatly appreciate it very much. Thanks!

Comment: Replace `$to` with the user's email address, and adjust `$body` to contain whatever text you want...

Comment: Show us yours form, and comment what do you need more detail

Comment: I wanted to send one to me and them one to them with the data they submitted in the form that includes a little message using there name and thanking them on submit of php form. I don't know any php so spell it out for me please thanks

Comment: @benlevywebdesign: Everything is spelled out pretty clearly [in the documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). It's generally expected that you put in some effort here. As it stands, it sounds like you want someone to write your code for you...

Comment: @Colin I tried doing somethings and it messed up the email to me so I just want to know where to place the new code and how to get started that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current code is already working fine, you can do this to send yourself an email together with the recipient:

1. Set `$to` to `$_POST['email']`
2. Set `$headers` to `"From: {$_POST['email']}\r\nBcc: benlevygraphics@gmail.com"`
3. Adjust `$body` and `$subject` to your needs.

Btw, I can't say this often enough; make sure that your page has some form of CSRF protection.

[How to properly add CSRF token using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287903/how-to-properly-add-csrf-token-using-php)

The above is just one way, there are others, just search for it :)

Comment: How do I send a different email to the user? I want to send a custom message to them with their name and a little message while just sending me a email like I have above.

Comment: In that case you have to just copy the code and change the email contents and subject.

Comment: ok I got it to send two messages but how do I add a custom message to the user email?

Comment: @benlevywebdesign customizing an email is the same as making a big string, using the posted fields as a part of it ... maybe I'm not entirely following what kind of customization you'd like to do

Comment: I got it and figured it out. Is it easy to add color or bold styles to my message?

Comment: If you're sending HTML email that should be no problem. Just keep on mind that CSS had to be applied inline because not all email clients understand style tag

Comment: Just add "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" to your `$headers` and create your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Look into your php.ini beacuse you have to enter a SMTP Server.
At my file it begins in line 1087 with "[mail function]"