# How to get the referrer url of post request in php?

Tags: javascript, php, security, post, httprequest

I'm developing a php website, where users are allowed to add products with descriptions, images etc. I am receiving the user input using POST method. But, if the users know the form input names and the form's action link, they can send constant requests using javascript and jam my database.

**So, if I could somehow get the URL from where the POST request is coming, I could prevent that. I could only input the information into database if the POST request was from my site's url.**

I know this attack may also be prevented using captcha, but I want an alternative, mainly because captchas are painful.

Any way I can do it without using captchas? Perhaps sessions?

Comment: Have you looked into [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)?

Comment: @UnholyRanger : yes, I have, doesn't seem to serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way to provide security to your Forms are by adding a CSRF Token to your form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

How it works is every time you render a form you generate a pseudo random code and store it in a session variable and also put the same code as a hidden input in your form.

So when the user posts the form you can validate to see if the csrf tokens are the same.

There is another thread about this so you can maybe take a look at that
([How to properly add CSRF token using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287903/how-to-properly-add-csrf-token-using-php))

Answer (score 0):

You could use the header to allow only post coming from your url:

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yoururl.com');
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks a lot :D .. 
and is this totally reliable ? I mean does this serve the purpose of captcha?

Comment: Yes, have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS "If the resource owners at http://bar.other wished to restrict access to the resource to be only from http://foo.example, they would send back:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example"

Answer (score 0):

You could check against the:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Variable, but this can be falsified so be careful.

You'd be better off using some hidden inputs that are set to values which must be equal to the set fields for the insert to happen (the name for this technique escapes me at the moment).

i.e.

```
<input type="text" id="areyouhuman" name="areyouhuman" value="123456001" />
```

Hide it with CSS:

```
#areyouhuman{
     display:none;
}
```

Hope that helps a little?

P.S. I HATE Captcha's too!

Comment: Well, not only with css, I could also make it <input type="hidden"/> so that no one could see it.. 
But if someone knows this hidden value they can easily send this value along with their attacking request.
As far as I think, network experts can dump post data and find out what is being posted.. i.e, it is possible for hackers to know the value of the hidden input... :(

Comment: I'd think that it would be far easier for a spambot to detect a hidden input than one that has been hidden by CSS, but I couldn't tell you for sure as I've never felt the need to use one.