# How to determine the originating URL of your $_POST variables?

Tags: php

I'm creating a simple app that submits some data and on the other end read the `$_POST` super global and show the passed data. Now I want to check that the `$_POST` is coming from my page/form, is there a variable that I can read in the `$_POST` or do I need to create a `nonce` and use it on my form after saving it to the session as valid/accepted id?

**edit**:even if I assign a nonce to my form, the user can simply copy it in his local page and post the data, there must be another way to check the origin of the posted data though.

Comment: Look into CSRF tokens. The token in the form will need to match the token in the session.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321842/how-to-get-the-referrer-url-of-post-request-in-php is the answer.

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to figure out which page the request originated from. However not all browser sets this and this can be changed as well so don't rely too much in this. Read more on php doc [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: @sohailansari so it is using the `nonce` as supposed?

Comment: @aynber can I skip that check if the form is behind a login and the page it post to check for actual `$_SESSION` and if not logged it redirect back to login?

Comment: Sure, if you set it up right, you can probably do that.