# External script send data back to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to develop something that would allow a site owner to include a script I provide to send back data to my server and return some HTML that gets appended into a `div` on the requesting site.

For example: Bob's Tires embeds my script in the header (or wherever)...something like this:

```
<script src="https://example.com/special.js"></script>
```

I would need data sent back to this script so I can return some HTML. In this case, find the div with a specific class and send me the class name.

```
<div class="special 123456></div> <!--this would be on Bob's site-->
```

What I would want back is the "123456". I know how to do this when writing the code to live all on the same page/domain, but how do I say

```
$(".special").prop("classList")
```

for Bob's Site and send this back to my server so I can send something back based on this data (i.e., something specific for "123456")?

Comment: Have you considered jsonp? Also see this: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Just because your javascript is hosted on a remote server doesn't mean that it isn't running on the page. It makes zero difference except for the fact that you need to send the data cross-domain.

Comment: @Turnip Good point. Are there any issues with sending the data cross-domain (assume it's not at all sensitive information)

Comment: Your server would need to allow cross-domain requests. Other than that it should be a straight forward ajax requests. If you are worried about security then that is [a whole other (huge) topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912937/how-to-send-secure-ajax-requests-with-php-and-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

In Bob's page:

```
<script src="//your_site.com/phpjs_test.php?id=123"></script>
```

In the `phpjs_test.php` on your site:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $res = ($_GET['id']==123) ? "abc": 758;
  echo 'document.write("'. $res .'");';
}
```

Some details and example to this subtitle: `Displaying data from PHP with JavaScript, according to a URL`, on this page: http://coursesweb.net/javascript/javascript-code-php