# XSS and CSRF Improvements

Tags: php, xss, csrf

So I'm building a PHP Web app and I need to make sure it's secure from XSS and CSRF. I have looked at articles and I know the methods to prevent these attacks. Like using htmlspecialchars or htmlentites for XSS  And for CSRF I need to use the random token method. However I'm not sure when to use which.

Do I create a method that uses htmlspecialchars and wrap it around every variable I want to print that a user has entered ? Most of the data in the Web app is stored into a database. I use prepared statements to do this, but do I still have to sanitize the input?

For CSRF is it necessary to generate a new token after every refresh or form submit or would one per session be okay.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31683058/5930557 for Generating a CSRF Token

Comment: Cheers dude, will have a look at that for the CSRF :)