# How to really prevent a request to a file when it's not in the normal workflow of the application?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I use Javascript to redirect to a file called `handle.php` which create a session for a user then redirect (this time with `header()` function of php) to the main page (where the user is then identified).

Here is the Javascript:

```
window.location.replace("handle.php");
```

In order, to prevent a hacker to execute directly `handle.php` I use this configuration in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^handle.php$ - [F]
```

But this code does not prevent the hacker to replay the request to `handle.php` and to add `Referer: http://localhost` in the headers, allowing him to execute `handle.php`.

So, I need a way to allow the execution of `handle.php` **only when it's in the proper workflow of my application**, i.e when it comes from a redirection that is written in my code.

Thank you

Comment: you could use a csrf token, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31683058/2535531

Comment: Why not call the main page directly (if it's PHP), and require once the handler.php file? You could set a constant in the main page and then check to see if it exists in handler.php, if not die with an unauthorized message.

Comment: @DRC How would you use it according to my problem please ?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Ok I see your point, but why would you use `require_once` instead of `require` ?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I just tested your solution, but I already include another page in my main page, and I get an error calling this latter, I am not sure that I can include several files

Comment: Without seeing what your code looks like, I don't know either. You should be able to call the php file near the start of your main page (if it is php). Also, you didn't say what the error is that you got when you tried it out, or what line caused the error.

Comment: @juRioqs75 could I ask why someone could not call handle.php directly? your authentication should be independent of that redirection/flow. the script that authenticates your user should also set something in the session to tell your user has logged in.