# Defined variable lost on form submission to another php file?

Tags: php

On my homepage .. index.php .. right up the top I define a constant to use in other php files, I'm trying to ensure that index has been loaded and the php files aren't accessed directly. I use ..

```
define('SOME_CONSTANT','something'); - index.php
```

There's a sign up form on index.php that sends the data to /php/signuphandle.php .. In signuphandle.php I have a check

```
if(!defined('CONSTANT_NAME')){ echo('nope'); }
```

The issue is it always hits the !defined block and echos "nope" .. I can't figure out why? I've looked up the documentation and lots of previous posts on this form to no avail. Am I just doing it wrong? Thanks for any help you guys can give.

Comment: A constant, or any other variable, is only defined in the script where it is defined, it does not carry over through form submissions to different files where the constant or variable is not defined.

Comment: Outside of sessions, PHP has no persistence of variables across requests.

Comment: Agreed with the above. However, this stands to be too broad also. I voted to close as "not working", as an "FYI" ;-)

Comment: Probably want something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287903/how-to-properly-add-csrf-token-using-php/31683058

Comment: Thanks guys .....

Comment: http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries