# PHP URL hiding the id of the category

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

I am having a doubt that my code "soon to be a website" is weak or easy to hack.

I have read about SQL injection and other security issues, I came to know that the URL should not be something like: "index.php?catid=id" it must be hidden or redirected or routed.

And this is what I am trying to avoid, however, I have tried session_start(); but ended up in a mess.

I might be wrong as well, there might be no danger at all when sending the user from a page to another using anchor click here

Kindly check the code below.

**header.php**

```
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" /></a>
</div><!--logo ends-->
<div class="navigation">
    <?php

        $cat_sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
        $cat_query = $conn->query($cat_sql);
        while ($cat_results = $cat_query->fetch_array()){
        $category_page = "category.php?categoryID=" .$cat_results['categoryID'];
            //session_start();
            //echo session_id();
            echo "<a href='$category_page'>". $cat_results['name'] ." </a>";
        }
    CloseCon($conn)
    ?>
        <a href="admin.php">Admin</a>
</div><!--navigation ends-->
</div><!-- Header ends here-->
```

**dbconnect.php**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456789";
$database = "accessories";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";a

function CloseCon($conn)
{$conn -> close();}
```

Comment: wait... why exactly is a `session_start()` and `session_id()` inside of a `while` ??

Comment: testing purposes only, just commented them out..

Comment: Are you worried that someone might simply 'know' that a category with ID x has a name of y? What exactly happens when you go to the category.php page?

Comment: no I am not worried, what I am worried about is **if** an ID is shown in the URL it might be open a security hole in the website? 
the category page will display such items, prices, pictures, etc.. nothing really important..

Comment: Since you're concerned about id exposure, you should look into [CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6287903/1144627), which can be used to validate requests from forms and query strings. And using [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for database queries as well. However as it stands, the code in your question is not vulnerable as you are not processing `$_GET, $_POST, $_FILE, $_COOKIE, or $_SESSION`, so your question is overall just too broad to provide a an appropriate answer for.

Comment: If nothing much happens other than displaying info then you are pretty safe. But if you were manipulating data/files etc on the basis of what was being sent you would be opening yourself up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd worry less about IDs being public (that's really not uncommon... it's the norm), and more about *how* you're querying.  Are you making use of [MySQLi's support for parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)?  They are, single-handedly, the best way to secure your website against SQL Injection vulnerabilities.  Anywhere you accept user input, and ship it in a query, ensure it's parameterized.

Comment: so I am all safe when sending the user from a page to another, yeah?

Comment: Again, I'd encourage you to make use of parameterized queries any time user input is required in a query.  That includes using an ID set via $_GET.  Never trust user input.