# prevent form submiting (post/get) if not in server php

Tags: php

Im testing a basic form in my `localhost` and my domain name server `domainexample.com`

And I need to authorize only the forms submitted in my site only `domainexample.com`

I made this prove

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['testEngine'])){

         $test=  $_POST['test'];

        echo $test;
     }
   //
   ?>
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<form method="POST" action="https://domainexample.com/form.php">
<input type="text" name="test" />
<input type="hidden" name="testEngine" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Im realizing that, if I submit this form from my localhost, it executes in my server, how do I prevent this behaviour? thank you.

Comment: I think most sites which try to prevent this type of thing employ techniques such as [CSRF tokens](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/tokens)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly add cross-site request forgery (CSRF) token using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287903/how-to-properly-add-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-token-using-php)

Comment: This is called CSRF - in effect you generate a token server side that the client needs to resubmit to the server for the form to be valid. That way other users can't make random people submit valid requests to your server.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you for your approach, is this necessary working with sessions in order to make csrf tokens work? becaus is a real problem for me coding sessions outside the user normal login session.

Comment: you should generate a CSRF token in your session, also submit this token in the form as hidden input, when hit the submit button, the system may verify the session token with the submitted one

Comment: @max You can have CSRF schemes that do not require a session; you can create a random value, then "sign" that random value using an HMAC and a secret key, then verify that the random value and signature is correct when the CSRF token is submitted again. It'll be easier to just store it in `$_SESSION`, but it's not necessary.

Comment: _"is a real problem for me coding sessions outside the user normal login session"_ ...why, exactly?

Comment: @ADyson because, I create a session during the register or the login process, before the user has created his own session. So, I create a session before the login, or before the register, and once the user is logged in this pre-user-session merges with the active user session. So several sessions. I just dont know

Comment: As far as PHP is concerned it's all one session. Sessions in PHP relate to the connection to a particular browser (implemented using cookies), not to a login. When the user logs in, you just add more variables to it, to indicate the login status. I think you're creating an artificial problem for yourself there

Comment: ok, thank you, Ill figure it out