# Working with CSRF token in JavaScript via Fetch API

Tags: javascript, laravel, fetch-api, csrf-token

I haven't practiced using CSRF tokens in JavaScript. Now I need to send the token to the server. Can I use POST request of fetch API for this, and how it is done? (I only know JavaScript. I don't understand AJAX, jQuery etc.).

Do I need to write something in the HTML file for my weapon with the token?
Running PHP Laravel for backend?

I have this code which gives me a 419 error:

```js
form1.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const formDatas = new FormData(form1);
  const data = new URLSearchParams(formDatas);

  fetch(f1_search_url, {
      headers: {
        "X-CSRF-Token": my_token, //  Set the token
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
})
```

Comment: your csrf token must be saved somewhere in your backend (e.g session table), and then when page is generated, you echo the token to where X-CSRF-Token is supposed to be. The csrf token is then matched with what is in the backend to see if it's a valid session.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31683058/2822041

Comment: How you send a CSRF token to the server depends entirely on how the server expects it to be sent. There's no universal answer.  (Sending a CSRF token to an API That expects a JSON content-type header seems pretty pointless though; you can't forget a request from a third party site with that header without bouncing off CORS).

Answer (score 3):

Use csrf-token in head meta tag

`<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

In Fetch Api need to add `credentials: "same-origin"`

```
<script>
const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf_token][content]").content;

form1.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const formDatas = new FormData(form1);
  const data = new URLSearchParams(formDatas);

  fetch(f1_search_url, {
      headers: {
        "X-CSRF-Token": my_token, //  Set the token
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: "same-origin"
      body: data
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
})
```